# How to create a query with all of dependencies in hierarchical organization?

Tags: sql, tree, recursive-query, hierarchical

I've been trying hard to create a query to see all dependencies in a hierarchical organization. But the only I have accuaried is to retrieve the parent dependency. I have attached an image to show what I need.

Thanks for any clue you can give me.

[image]

This is the code I have tried with the production table.

```
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT
        H1.systemuserid,
        H1.pes_aprobadorid,
        H1.yomifullname,
        H1.internalemailaddress
    FROM [dbo].[ext_systemuser] H1
    WHERE H1.pes_aprobadorid is null
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        H2.systemuserid,
        H2.pes_aprobadorid,
        H2.yomifullname,
        H2.internalemailaddress           
    FROM [dbo].[ext_systemuser] H2
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON h2.pes_aprobadorid=c.systemuserid)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with your query. You just have to include all rows as a starting point. Also the `join` should be `cte.parent_id = ext.user_id` and not the other way round. I've done an example query in `postgres`, but you shall easily adapt it to your DBMS.

> ```
> with recursive st_units as (
>   select 0 as id, NULL as pid, 'Director' as nm
>   union all select 1, 0, 'Department 1'
>   union all select 2, 0, 'Department 2'
>   union all select 3, 1, 'Unit 1'
>   union all select 4, 3, 'Unit 1.1'
> ),
> cte AS
> (
> SELECT id, pid, cast(nm as text) as path, 1 as lvl
> FROM st_units
>
> UNION ALL
> SELECT c.id, u.pid, cast(path || '->' || u.nm as text), lvl + 1
> FROM st_units as u
>   INNER JOIN cte as c on c.pid = u.id
> )
> SELECT id, pid, path, lvl
> FROM cte
> ORDER BY lvl, id
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  pid | path                                     | lvl
> -: | ---: | :--------------------------------------- | --:
>  0 | null | Director                                 |   1
>  1 |    0 | Department 1                             |   1
>  2 |    0 | Department 2                             |   1
>  3 |    1 | Unit 1                                   |   1
>  4 |    3 | Unit 1.1                                 |   1
>  1 | null | Department 1->Director                   |   2
>  2 | null | Department 2->Director                   |   2
>  3 |    0 | Unit 1->Department 1                     |   2
>  4 |    1 | Unit 1.1->Unit 1                         |   2
>  3 | null | Unit 1->Department 1->Director           |   3
>  4 |    0 | Unit 1.1->Unit 1->Department 1           |   3
>  4 | null | Unit 1.1->Unit 1->Department 1->Director |   4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e1ad9b1aa808792a4c4223dc199c95fe)*

Answer (score 0):

I've reached this code that it is working but when I include a hierarchy table of more than 1800 the query is endless.

```
With cte AS
(select systemuserid, systemuserid as pes_aprobadorid, internalemailaddress, yomifullname
from @TestTable
union all
SELECT c.systemuserid, u.pes_aprobadorid, u.internalemailaddress, u.yomifullname
FROM @TestTable as u
INNER JOIN cte as c on c.pes_aprobadorid = u.systemuserid
)
select distinct * from cte
where pes_aprobadorid is not null
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```